# "Vanishing locus" of forms in the $h$-topology

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, birational-geometry, group-schemes

Let $\Omega_{h}^p$ be the sheaf of $p$-forms in the $h$-topology defined as the sheafification for the $h$-topology of the presheaf,

$$ Y \mapsto \Omega^p_Y(Y) $$

[Kebekus and Schnell](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1811.03644.pdf) show that when $X$ has rational singularities $\Omega^p_h(X) = \Omega^{[p]}_X(X)$ where the right-hand side is the reflexive hull of $\Omega^p_X$. This equivalence is used, in particular, to show functoriality for the reflexive forms. I am interested in how well one can talk about the vanishing locus of forms on singular varieties using this formalism.

For example, I would like a notion of ``vanishing locus'' for reflexive or h-forms on mildly singular varieties such that the following is true: if $\pi : X \to Y$ is a proper map with $X$ smooth and $\omega$ is a form on $Y$ then if $\pi^* \omega$ is nonvanishing (in the usual sense) then $\omega$ is nonvanishing (in the new sense).

Even on smooth varieties, I am not sure how to make sense of the vanishing locus of an h-form without passing first to ordinary differential forms.

The root of my confusion is the following. Let $\omega \in \Omega^p_h(X)$ and consider the map $s_{\omega} : \mathcal{O}_h \to \Omega^p_h(X)$. Even if $\omega$ arose from a nonvanishing form under the identification $\Omega^p_h(X) = \Omega^p_X(X)$ (here $X$ is smooth) it is not clear that $s_{\omega}$ should be injective. This should be checked by passing to all absolutely integrally closed valuation rings mapping to $X$. However, many of these factor through exceptionals of blowups of $X$ at points so I would expect the form to pick up a vanishing locus on these exceptional divisors and hence for $s_{\varphi}$ to not be injective on these valuation rings.

What is the correct story? Apologies for my complete ignorance about the $h$-topology.